# How refer to God and the devil using pronouns and adverbs?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, religion

I'm trying to phrase a sentence where I want to refer to the god and the devil/satan by using a combination of pronouns and adverbs rather than their names or nouns such as "good/evil", "divine power" or similar. It is important that the sentence is using the masculine pronouns, if possible.
The sentence should begin with "Here it is close to both..." (as in, this place is vertically in the middle of god and devil)

This sounds best to me:

> Here it is close to both him above and him down below.

Alternative that doesn't sound as good:

> Here it is close to both him up there and him down there.

My problem concerns what combination of pronoun and adverbs to use. English is not my native language so this isn't very obvious to me.

Also, should I capitalize Him?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a huge difference between saying "Him up above/Him down below" or simply "Him above/Him below"? (and thanks for noticing the parallelism!)

Comment: If you would capitalize, then just capitalize the `Him` for God.

Comment: @hysteryteacher: Nope, not a big difference. Use whichever sounds best to you.

Comment: This question is fine right where it is, but, since you mentioned that English is not your native language, you may want to check out [ell.se], too. (If you're wondering about the differences between the two sites, read [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).)

Comment: Thanks guys!  @William Bloom maybe you can move your comments into a proper answer so I can vote on it.

Comment: Him and ɥim ...

Comment: As the poster was a non-native speaker it is a pity that those discussing his question in comments instead of answering it properly never thought to suggest that he apply himself to finding what is wrong with his title.

Answer (score 2):

> Here it is close to both **H**im above and **h**im down below.

Traditionally in Christianity, and hence to older English-speaking parts of the world, God, out of respect, has His pronouns (He, Him, His, Thou, Thine, Thy, Thee, You, Your, Yours) capitalised.

Satan is not accorded this courtesy.

Comment: If you think this question worth answering, you might correct the English in its title. Helps the site, helps your answer and helps the poster (if he is still with us). I’d do it myself but don’t wish my handle associated with the question, which I personally would close.